# Что за кодировка в php скрипте?

Tags: php, кодировка, перекодировка

Есть скрипт в utf-8 без Boom, в нем подчеркнул фрагмент кода в непонятной кодировке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Когда я копирую этот фрагмент кода (Ctr+C) и вставляю **в этом же**, либо в любом другом текстовом файле или текстовой области (Ctr+V), то у меня без перекодирования он же отображается как: `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(` и тут же на этот файл кидается антивирь и убивает его. Пока же этот фрагмент кода находится в этой непонятной перекодировке, антивирь на него не реагирует.

Что за кодировка, которая на лету при копи-пасте отображается уже в читаемом виде и за которой антивирь не видит реального кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат `\xAA` является представлением символа с шестнадцатеричным кодом `AA`

В вашем случае,

```
\x65 = e
\x76 = v
```

и так далее. В итоге собирается строка `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(`

В этой строке

`base64_decode` - Декодирует данные, закодированные алгоритмом MIME base64.

`gzinflate` — Распаковывает строку

`eval` - Исполняет строку, переданную в параметре code, как код PHP

Т.е. на вход `base64_decode` подается некая кодированная строка (та, которая у вас после "непонятных символов"), она декодируется, распоковывается(`gzinflate`) и выполняется у вас на сервере(`eval`).

Другими словами, кто-то подсунул вам во входные данные вируса/бекдора/шифровальщика/еще какую гадость в надежде, что ваши скрипты не валидируют пользовательские данные, он запустится и устроит вам веселую жизнь. Вы же валидируете данные?

Ради интереса можете убрать из этой строки `eval`, и посмотреть, в какой конкретно код декодируется эта строка.